# FindResource() in C# WPF .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, wpf

Im am a newcomer to C# and to WPF. So I am trying to work through a tutorial ( https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/resources/ ).

Concerning Resources, they say:

"Notice how we use the FindResource() method on different scopes - first on the panel, then on the window and then on the current Application object. It makes sense to look for the resource where we know it is, but as already mentioned, if a resource is not found, the search progresses up the hierarchy, so in principal, we could have used the FindResource() method on the panel in all three cases, since it would have continued up to the window and later on up to the application level, if not found."

But on my system, it does not work! (`TryFindResource()` returns null).

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="_03_ResourcesFromCodeBehindSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_03_ResourcesFromCodeBehindSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ResourcesFromCodeBehindSample" Height="175" Width="250">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="strWindow">Hello, Window world!</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel Margin="10" Name="pnlMain">
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <sys:String x:Key="strPanel">Hello, Panel world!</sys:String>
        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Button Name="btnClickMe" Margin="10" Click="btnClickMe_Click">Funktioniert!</Button>
            <Button Name="btnAbsturz" Margin="10" Click="btnAbsturz_Click">Stürzt ab!</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <ListBox Name="lstBox" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

<Application x:Class="_03_ResourcesFromCodeBehindSample.App"             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_03_ResourcesFromCodeBehindSample"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="strApp">Hello, Application world!</sys:String>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace _03_ResourcesFromCodeBehindSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstBox.Items.Add(pnlMain.FindResource("strPanel").ToString());
            lstBox.Items.Add(this.FindResource("strWindow").ToString());
          lstBox.Items.Add(Application.Current.FindResource("strApp").ToString());
        }

        private void btnAbsturz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { /* Das folgende stürzt ab! Warum, weiss ich noch nicht.
             Gemäss Dokumentation sollte das doch funktionieren!
           */

            lstBox.Items.Add(FindResource("strPanel").ToString());
            lstBox.Items.Add(FindResource("strWindow").ToString());
            lstBox.Items.Add(FindResource("strApp").ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Tanks a so much for answering.

Paul

Comment: Where are you calling `TryFindResource`? Which particular resource lookup fails?

Comment: In the present code, I do not call TryFindResource. It was just a test tu verify that nothing is found. I am calling FindResource.

Comment: Just the first call in "private void btnAbsturz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" fails.

Comment: This Button works as expected:private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstBox.Items.Add(pnlMain.FindResource("strPanel").ToString());
            lstBox.Items.Add(this.FindResource("strWindow").ToString());
            lstBox.Items.Add(Application.Current.FindResource("strApp").ToString());
        }

Comment: You need to call `pnlMain.FindResource()` for all three calls, not `FindResource()`, just like the documentation is trying to explain to you.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, your code within the `btnAbsturz_Click()` method is using `FindResource()`, not `pnlMain.FindResource()`. In C#, the `FindResource()` method is secretly preceded with the `this` keyword, turning it into `this.FindResource()`. That is why your first call is failing.

If you replace the body of that method with

```
private void btnAbsturz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    lstBox.Items.Add(pnlMain.FindResource("strPanel").ToString());
    lstBox.Items.Add(pnlMain.FindResource("strWindow").ToString());
    lstBox.Items.Add(pnlMain.FindResource("strApp").ToString());
}
```

it should work as expected.

See here for more info on this keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this